# what is the difference between (*object)[0] and (*object)[1]

Tags: c++, pointers

I've found a code snippet and dont understand what the index [1] and [0] does after the (*object)

the objects:

```
Edge *edgea = new Edge(vertex_a,triangle);
Edge *edgeb = new Edge(vertex_b,triangle);
```

the call:

```
Edge *edgea_opposite = getEdge((*edgea)[1],(*edgea)[0]);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no array here. But `operator[]` can be overloaded for a class. [For instance, `std::vector` does so that it can be used like an array.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)

So `Edge` must have overloaded this. We can't tell you what it does, since we don't have the definition, and we don't know if it is from some publicly available library, or is private to your company/project/whatever.

But guessing from the context, I would think `someEdge[0]` gets the start of the line segment, and `someEdge[1]` gets the end of it. Creating a new `Edge` with these swapped around creates the "opposite" edge. Hence the name.

Comment: ty for your answer ;) its true, the edge class has overloaded the operator []
Vertex* operator[](int i) const { 
    if (i==0) return getVertex();
    if (i==1) return getNext()->getNext()->getVertex();
    assert(0);
  }